# A 3rd degree polynomial $P(x)$ has three unequal real roots. What is the least possible # of unequal real roots for $P(x^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I got that if P(x) is a 3rd degree polynomial then P($x^2$) must be a 6th degree polynomial.

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: If $p(x)=a_0 + a_1 x+ a_2 x^2+a_3 x^3$, so what do think $p(x^2)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factor $P(x) = (x - a)(x - b)(x - c)$ for distinct real numbers. Then how can you factor $P(x^2)$ and what happens if, say, some of these numbers were negative?

Comment: $P\left( x^{2} \right)\; =\; \left( x^{2}-a \right)\left( x^{2}-b \right)\left( x^{2}-c \right)$

Comment: If the roots were negative, then it would be factored as $P\left( x^{2} \right)\; =\; \left( x^{2}+a \right)\left( x^{2}+b \right)\left( x^{2}+c \right)$. This equation doesn't have any real roots because it is always > 0, right? So is the min. number of real roots 0?

Comment: @user2612743 Almost: The first comment was correct, and the important fact is that each factor looks like $x^2 + \text{something positive}$.

Comment: I updated my second comment with what I think might be the answer. Is it right?

Comment: @user2612743 Yes, with the caveat that it really does factor as $(x^2 - a)(x^2 - b)(x^2 - c) = (x^2 + |a|)(x^2 + |b|)(x^2 + |c|)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: call the roots of $P(x)$ $a$, $b$, and $c$.  $a$, $b$, and $c$ are three distinct real numbers.  The roots of $P(x^2)$ are $\{\sqrt{a},-\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b},-\sqrt{b}, \sqrt{c},-\sqrt{c}\}$ (a set of possibly complex numbers with possibly repeated elements, that is, fewer than six) . What is the minimum possible number of distinct real numbers in the set $\{\sqrt{a},-\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b},-\sqrt{b}, \sqrt{c},-\sqrt{c}\}$?

Comment: If a, b, and c are all negative it is 0 real roots, right?

Comment: @user2612743 : right!